# Custom "Files Connect" integration between asset management system and Salesforce

Tags: externalobjects, salesforce-connect, files-connect

Is possible to set up a Files Connect integration (that behaves like the existing out-of-box Files Connect integrations - Box, Google Drive, Sharepoint, etc) with a custom digital asset management system?

If not, what sort of setup would you recommend? Perhaps setting up a "Salesforce Connect" type external data source, with display urls simply links to the assets in the external system?